# Probability of TH over HH

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting TH before HH when rolling a fair coin? I know the number of rolls we would need to get each of those but I don't know how to solve this particular question.

Thanks

Comment: The probability is 75%. Have you made any effort to look up on the web. You have asked questions in succession, but not made or shown your own efforts. All I am saying is that if you show your efforts, the community will definitely help and it will benefit you in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the first two throws are HH, you will always get TH first because HH must be preceded by a T.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering, as we wouldn't be able to use the same logic, how would we find the probability of getting HH before HT?

Comment: There it is $50/50$  You wait until the first heads, then the next flip determines the winner.  There is a general procedure for finding these probabilities.  I haven't studied it carefully, but it depends on the overlap between the first characters of one string and the last of the other.   With some searching, there should be papers out there that do it.  I don't have a link.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.